# Are there any terms equivalent to 'Americana' for other cultures?

Tags: nouns, terminology, demonyms

Given the available definition of [Americana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americana) as pertaining to "artifacts, or a collection of artifacts, related to the history, geography, folklore and cultural heritage of the United States", are there any equivalent terms which pertain to folklore and cultural heritage of locales or cultures other than those of the United States?

Comment: While this isn't exactly about demonyms, it's closely related to them so I added the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three suffixes principally added to a concept to represent all things relating to that concept:

> **[-ana](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/-ana)**  (or *-iana*) : (Forming plural nouns) denoting things associated with a person, place, or field of interest: *Americana*, *Victoriana*

Examples in the wild include *[Australiana](http://data.gov.au/dataset/australiana-index-state-library-of-victoria)*, *[Canadiana](http://canadiana.library.ualberta.ca/)*, *[Kiwiana](http://schools.natlib.govt.nz/resources-learning/high-interest-topics/kiwiana)*, and *[Rhodesiana](http://www.rhodesia.nl/indexrhosoc.html)*, noting that Rhodesiana applies specifically to Rhodesia and not the modern state of Zimbabwe.

This seems to be the most productive suffix, and a web search will turn up a scattering of results for *collection of* + *Egyptiana*, *Hiberniana* (for Ireland), *Israeliana*,  *Vietnamiana*, and even *South Africana*.

> **[-ica](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ica#English)** : a collection of things that relate to a specific place, person, theme, etc.

This is an older lot, but some terms in active use include [*Hebraica* and *Judaica*](http://library.columbia.edu/locations/rbml/units/Hebraica.html) (pertaining to the Hebrew and Jewish people), *[Hispanica](http://special.lib.gla.ac.uk/exhibns/hispanica/hispanica.html)* (Spain), and *[Nipponica](http://www.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/bodley/finding-resources/special/oriental_rarebooks/japan)* (Japan), although the last sounds dated to me. *Japonica* is a word, but seems only to refer to plants originated in Japan.

> **[-ia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ia)** : 2. things derived from or relating to (something specified): *militaria*

I could not think of any examples in current usage for a particular country. It is suggested to be more productive than *-ica*, but since so many countries already end in *-ia* or *-a*, it would not make a suitable derived form in this particular set.

Answer (score 4):

[Australiana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australiana) has an almost identical meaning for items of historical and cultural interest from Australia. It is also the name of a famous (in Australia) comedy skit from the 80's by [Austen Tayshus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australiana_%28song%29).

Answer (score 1):

You might add *Judaica* to the same list.

> 1. the literature, customs, culture, etc, of the Jews.
> 2. books or artefacts of Jewish interest, esp as a collection.

The meaning is perhaps more restricted than *Americana* and *Australiana*, and incorporates a different morpheme, but is in the same ball park.

The morpheme -*a*, added to adjectives in -*an*, -*ean*, -*ian*, is not only restricted to demonyms, though.  One also has, for instance, *Dickensiana*, and *Shakespearena*.  In a similar vein, there is a collection of essays in defence of evolution by Asa Gray, called *Darwiniana*, and the popular name of one of Tchaikovsky’s suites is *Mozartiana*.

Answer (score -3):

A less colloquial alternative would be ["material culture"](http://chnm.gmu.edu/worldhistorysources/unpacking/objhist.html).

Comment: It feels like this is an answer to a different question, i.e. what is a less colloquial alternative to 'Americana'. I was looking for equivalent terms (which could be used in place of this term) which describe cultures _other_ than those of the United States.

Comment: Americana is, essentially, American material culture, but *material culture* can and is used to describe other cultures.  For example:  "Soviet material culture provides an interesting perspective on how the cold war was perceived by Russians."